# sendKeys() triggers NoSuchElementException for input field with auto complete off

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver 2.32. There is a particular field

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" id="login_password" name="login_password" value="" class="restricted large" />
```

Consider:

```
ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_password']");
System.out.println(passwordField.isDisplayed());  // returns true;

passwordField.sendKeys("password");
```

The above line throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element (Session info: chrome=26.0.1410.64)
```

Does the `autocomplete="Off"` matter?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the password field is not present inside a frame?

Comment: I suggest to check this in 2 ways, 1. Check whether it is in a iframe. 2. Put a Thread.sleep temporarily before entering text. coz sometimes input fields takes time to be editable even though it is visible. if it works then renove thread.sleep and put some wait methods

Comment: Another thing to check is that you have 'restricted' as a class. Is this blocking input to the field externally?